# Can I overlap magnet wire when wrapping a toroid or must it progress linearly around the circumference?

Tags: electromagnetism, hall-effect, ferrite, toroidal

I've been playing with inducing magnetic fields in a ferrite toroid with turns of magnet wire.  Can you overlap, e.g. double back over the previous turns so I don't need a larger toroid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When current flows in a coil there's a magnetic field being generated, this magnetic field has more or less a shape of a donut. It doesn't matter where it starts or ends, as long as the current generating the magnetic field is always strengthening the "donut".

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, and it's often done with commercial power transformers. But.

It is critical that you guarantee that each layer of windings is isolated from the others. This is usually done with a layer of Kraft paper or something like Teflon tape.

Comment: It's not clear from your answer when you would require layer insulation. Most windings are made with enamel-coated wire which is insulating so no further insulation is required.